# Thymeleaf .html passing parameter to MVC Spring Controller Java

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

im new to thymeleaf and Spring - im doing some small project to my school class and i have a problem with html link. I had troubles with it for 2hours now and im editing my code in 10 diffrent ways so please answer how to do it properly. Below its my html template (i tried using here th:href with two diffrent ways:

```
<table>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>See</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <a th:each=" i : ${workouts}"  varStatus="status">
                <tr>
                    <td><a th:text="${i.getName()}"/></td>
                    <td><a th:text="${i.getDate()}"/></td>
                    <td><a href="seeWorktoutPage.html" th:href="@{'/seeWorkoutPage/'${i.getId()}}">See</a></td>
                    <td><a href="seeWorktoutPage.html" th:href="@{seeWorkoutPage(id=${i.getId()})}">See</a></td>                    </tr>
                </a>
            </table>
```

And here its my Controller:
@Controller
public class SeeWorkoutController {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/seeWorkoutPage/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET, params="id")
public String test2(@PathVariable("id")Long id, Model model) {
        System.out.println(id);
        return "workoutsPage";
    }
```

but it's now working properly. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for [Thymeleaf Link URLs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls). In particular this example:

```
<!-- Will produce '/gtvg/order/3/details' (plus rewriting) -->
<a href="details.html" th:href="@{/order/{orderId}/details(orderId=${o.id})}">view</a>
```

I think you're almost there with your second example, but it should read

```
th:href="@{/seeWorkoutPage/{workoutId}(workoutId=${i.getId()})}"
```

Note how you specify the `{workoutId}` parameter, then give it's value between the brackets afterwards.

Comment: Ok, now it's working. But tell me now how i should come back to another html page? When i return "myAnotherPageName" or return "redirect:myAnotherPageName" i get: 
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "goToWorkoutsPage"
I want my link to look like:  http://localhost:8080/goToWorkoutsPage  but my is: http://localhost:8080/seeWorkoutPage/goToWorkoutsPage

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<span th:each="workout: ${workouts}">
    <td><a th:text="${workout.name}"/></td>
    <td><a th:text="${#dates.format(workout.date,'MMM d, yyyy')}</td>
    <!-- add other stuff when you have the above working -->
</span>
```

You don't need the `get()` syntax (and it can throw an exception in some containers).  Also, it looks like you're nesting anchor (`<a>`) tags too.